# Why is the beginning of the string overwritten instead of pasting it to the end?

Tags: c#

I'm building a temperature logger.

screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQ5s7.jpg;

```
while (true)
{
      string line = myport.ReadLine(); // line = *"T: 18.40"*

      if (line.StartsWith("T"))
      {
          line = line.Substring(3) + "°C";
          Console.WriteLine(line);
          // output is *"°C.40"* instead of *"T: 18.40°C"*                   
      }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your code. Are you sure your `line` is _really_ `T: 18.40`?

Comment: Agree with Soner, this code should work as expected. At least if you expect "18.40°C". You wrote "T: 18.40°C" but "18.40°C" is what you actually want, right?

Comment: If the input is as you say, then this code will output `18.40°C`.

Comment: An ideal moment to learn about the debugger and C# literal string notation.

Comment: The debugger is your friend...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely your input line is ending with `"\r"`, the output on the console screen is not a good representation of what the line actually is.

```
Console.WriteLine("18.40\r°C")
```

will look on the screen like

> °C.40

one solution is to clean the input from myport (a SerialPort I guesss?)

```
string line = myport.ReadLine(); // line = "T: 18.40\r"
line = line.Trim();              // remove all leading/trailing whitespace
```

But it shouldn't have happened. The ReadLine() should have removed the line ending. Somehow your `myport.NewLine` property is set to `"\n"` while it should be `"\r\n"`.

Comment: This was the solution!

Answer (score -1):

The line is most likely not what you expect it to be. 
Try this, it might be more stable.

```
line = line.Split(' ').Last() + "°C";
```

Comment: This has the same output